# jQuery loop though DOM elements and remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have some HTML elements like so

```
<input type="hidden" name="combos[0][pics][01]">
<input type="hidden" name="combos[0][pics][02]">
<input type="hidden" name="combos[1][pics][01]">
<input type="hidden" name="combos[1][pics][02]">
<input type="hidden" name="combos[2][pics][01]">
<input type="hidden" name="combos[2][pics][02]">
```

How can I use jquery's `$.each` function to loop through these and remove each DOM element ending in `[pics][02]`.

Comment: You don't need to use each explicitly.  Just find them, and use remove().  jQuery will do an implicit each over the entire result stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ending with selector `$=` and the full selector could be simply like :

```
'input[type="hidden"][name$="[pics][02]'
```

And you don't need a loop :

```
$('input[type="hidden"][name$="[pics][02]').remove();
```

Calling the `remove()` function on the selector result will remove them all.

**NOTE :** As *@David Thomas*'s comment says that could be done using pure JS like :

```
 document.querySelectorAll('input[type=hidden][name$="[pics][02]"').forEach((el)=>el.remove());
```

```js
console.log('Length BEFORE remove : ' + $('input[type="hidden"]').length);

$('input[type="hidden"][name$="[pics][02]').remove();

console.log('Length AFTER remove : ' + $('input[type="hidden"]').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" name="combos[0][pics][01]">
<input type="hidden" name="combos[0][pics][02]">
<input type="hidden" name="combos[1][pics][01]">
<input type="hidden" name="combos[1][pics][02]">
<input type="hidden" name="combos[2][pics][01]">
<input type="hidden" name="combos[2][pics][02]">
```

Comment: While this is a jQuery question, it's worth pointing out that this is quite possible with plain JavaScript: `document. querySelectorAll ('input[type=hidden][name$="[pics][02]"').forEach((el)=>el.remove());`

Comment: Thanks for your intervention, you suggestion added now to the answer...

Comment: @DavidThomas it's nice to see someone suggesting the js equivalent rather than being all evangelical and ranting how pointless it is to use jquery for a one liner when there's a js version and all us jquery developers are deluding ourselves yada yada :)

Comment: @freedomn-m: I'm one of those people that learned JavaScript almost entirely by accident from using - and asking so many questions about - jQuery here on SO that it would be entirely hypocritical to criticise others for preferring/using jQuery. I do, *now*, prefer plain JavaScript and believe that, with ES6, the need for jQuery is decreasing, but I'm still not going to try bullying people into changing their preferred workflow. In this instance, though, it was more about creating a more-complete answer in order to reduce future duplicates... :)